# DOS Batch File & FOR statements

Tags: batch-file

Using Win 7 Professional and trying to write a batch file to launch all batch files in a specified directory.

I see I can use FOR statements but am struggling with getting the syntax correct to get a list of *.bat files and run each one.  I get errors about %%f or %%b was unexpected.

Comment: for %%a in ("c:\a_folder_contains_bat\\*.bat") do call "%%~a"

Comment: I got this to work:

FOR %a in (<path>/*.bat) do (call "%A")

It starts the batch files successfully but one right after another; any thought on how to launch them at the same time?

Comment: would you like to try FOR %a in (<path>/*.bat) do (start cmd.exe /c "%A") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to launch  number of batch files in parallel..

FOR %a in (*.bat) do (start cmd /c "%a")